# train model using tf.data.Dataset of tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory is very slow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory to load my large dataset. the problem is the training phase is so slow when I exploit this method in `fit_generator()` although I use the google Colab GPU.
The code is:

```py
image_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32

data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
     '/content/drive/My Drive/dataScience/september exam/data/trainImg',
    seed=1337,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

for the training:

```py
model.fit_generator(train_dataset,
             epochs=50,
             verbose=1)
```

Comment: Use `fit()` instead of `fit_generator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reduce the image shape to 128x128, reduce the batch_size and use the GPU of the Collab, you should use `model.fit()` .Hope this helps you with time optimization.